# disable arrow keys in Slider

Tags: python, pyqt, scikit-image, eventfilter

When using scikit CollectionViewer (simple image browser) I'd like pressing arrow keys not to trigger going to prev/next image after slider got focus. I used eventFilter for that

```
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
from skimage.viewer.qt import Qt
from skimage.viewer.widgets import Slider

class SilentViewer(ImageViewer): #CollectionViewer with some modifications

    def __init__(self, image_collection, update_on='move', **kwargs):
        self.image_collection = image_collection
        self.index = 0
        self.num_images = len(self.image_collection)

        first_image = image_collection[0]
        super(SilentViewer, self).__init__(first_image)

        slider_kws = dict(value=0, low=0, high=self.num_images - 1)
        slider_kws['update_on'] = update_on
        slider_kws['callback'] = self.update_index
        slider_kws['value_type'] = 'int'
        self.slider = Slider('frame', **slider_kws)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.installEventFilter(self) #Modification to CollectionViewer №1

    def update_index(self, name, index):
        index = int(round(index))

        if index == self.index:
            return

        index = max(index, 0)
        index = min(index, self.num_images - 1)

        self.index = index
        self.slider.val = index
        self.update_image(self.image_collection[index])

    def eventFilter(self,obj,evt): #Modification to CollectionViewer №2
        try:
            print(evt.type(), evt.key(), evt.text())
            if (evt.key() == Qt.Key_Left or
                evt.key() == Qt.Key_Right or
                evt.key() == Qt.Key_Up or
                evt.key() == Qt.Key_Down):

                print("Ignored arrow button")
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            print("Smth went wrong")
            return False

#for testing reasons
from skimage import data
from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian

img = data.coins()
img_pyr = pyramid_gaussian(img, downscale=2, multichannel=False)
img_collection = tuple(img_pyr)
viewer = SilentViewer(img_collection)
viewer.show()
```

event filter seems to be working: key presses and other events trigger console output. However, arrow keys trigger image change. If I change to `update_on='release'` (see init), arrow keys do not trigger the image change, but make slider position change.
Could you please tell how can I make the arrow presses to be full consumed by the filter?

Comment: Could you add imports so that your code is an MRE ?, and so you could test and analyze your code.

Comment: Added the imports.

Comment: You focus a lot on the filter instead of explaining your goal, could you explain to me what happens before using the filter, what happens after using the filter, and what you want to happen.

Comment: I observe that Without the filter and if the Slider is focused and I press the arrow keys then the slider moves and therefore the image changes since the callback is invoked. Do you want the same thing to happen when you change from "move" to "release"?

Comment: Before (using source CollectionViewer): when slider gets focus after click, pressing arrow keys triggers image change (right and up for nex image in collection, left and down for previous). Image change can be also done dragging slider or clicking on slider position.

Comment: What I want: Image should be changed only by mouse (clicking or dragging slider). Arrow keys should be ignored

Comment: What I have (with SilentViewer): with `update_on='move'` I get exactly the same behavior as using source CollectionViewer. However, "Ignored arrow button" is emitted. With `update_on='release'` arrow keys do not trigger image change (and that's OK), but they affect slider position (that's not OK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyzing [the Slider source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/viewer/widgets/core.py#L50), it can be seen that it is a container, that is, a widget that has other widgets (QLabel, QSlider and QLineEdit), so the filter must be installed on the internal QSlider and not on the container.

```
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
from skimage.viewer.qt import QtCore
from skimage.viewer.widgets import Slider


class SilentViewer(ImageViewer):  # CollectionViewer with some modifications
    def __init__(self, image_collection, update_on="move", **kwargs):
        self.image_collection = image_collection
        self.index = 0
        self.num_images = len(self.image_collection)

        print(self.num_images)

        first_image = image_collection[0]
        super(SilentViewer, self).__init__(first_image)

        slider_kws = dict(value=0, low=0, high=self.num_images - 1)
        slider_kws["update_on"] = update_on
        slider_kws["callback"] = self.update_index
        slider_kws["value_type"] = "int"
        self.slider = Slider("frame", **slider_kws)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.slider.slider.installEventFilter(self)

    def update_index(self, name, index):
        if index == self.index:
            return
        index = max(index, 0)
        index = min(index, self.num_images - 1)
        self.index = index
        self.update_image(self.image_collection[index])

    def eventFilter(self, obj, evt):
        if obj is self.slider.slider and evt.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if evt.key() in (
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Left,
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Right,
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Up,
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Down,
            ):
                return True
        return super(SilentViewer, self).eventFilter(obj, evt)


def main():
    # for testing reasons
    from skimage import data
    from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian

    img = data.coins()
    img_pyr = pyramid_gaussian(img, downscale=2, multichannel=False)
    img_collection = tuple(img_pyr)
    viewer = SilentViewer(img_collection)
    viewer.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, your code does exactly what I want. I hoped that we can "filter out" an unwanted event at container level, i.e. evt.type() == 51 (ShortcutOverride).